# Как реализовать покраску стен в 2d игре на unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем добрый день! В Google play есть игра "house paint".В ней, как я понял, нужно закрашивать стены, и когда все стены закрашены игрок переходит на новый уровень. Вот в моей игре должна быть похожая механика, но у меня нет идей как можно её реализовать. Если вы знаете как можно это решить, то пожалуйста напишите или дайте ссылку на форум с решением. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: То есть, идея в том, что есть "кисть", которая может двигаться вверх/вниз/влево/вправо до препятствия (оконная рама, дверной проём и. т. д.) и она оставляет за собой крашенный след (я никогда о house paint не слышал, поэтому не знаю что нужно сделать)

Comment: Да, всё верно, только у меня не получается узнать полностью ли закрашена стена

Comment: ОК, тогда пожалуйста добавьте ваш код, информацию о том, как вы уже пытались это сделать. Без них модераторы могут удалить вопрос как слишком общий.

Answer (score 0):

вот это покраска одного блока стены

```
`public class PaintingOver : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PaintingManager _wallsSorting;
    private Color _defaultColor;
    public bool isPainted = false;
    private void Start()
    {
        _defaultColor = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
        _wallsSorting = GameObject.Find("Walls").GetComponent<PaintingManager>();
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Sponge") 
        {
            Color SpongeColor = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = SpongeColor;
            isPainted = true;

            _wallsSorting.PaintedWallsSorting(isPainted);
        }
    }
}`
```

а это счётчик покрашенных стен, но он работает не корректно в плане того, что если кисть соприкасается со стеной, то стена будет добавлятся в список бесконечно
`

```
public class PaintingManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PaintingOver[] walls;
    public List<PaintingOver> _paintedWalls;

    public void PaintedWallsSorting(bool isPainted)
    {
        foreach (var wall in walls)
        {
            if (!wall.isPainted)
            {
                continue;
            }

            _paintedWalls.Add(wall);
        }
        Debug.Log(_paintedWalls.Count);
    }
}`
```